# Angular torque and velocity on different children of same parent

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is my 3d object.

```
Target
  |-- Body
  |-- Label
```

Body is a 3d capsule
Label is a text field

I want this object to hang around in space and get knocked away when something collides with it. But i want the whole object, Target, to move away from the collision with the normal physical simulation. I dont want the body to move in its local space. However the rotational force (angular torque) should only affect the Body and not the Target object which always should have a rotation of 0,0,0 not to affect the Label and other children of Target.

This should be a quite normal situation but i cant remember seen any typical solution for it. How is this normally done?

Comment: Unity3D has always had an issue with multiple RigidBodies in a hierarchy (ie. an RB on a parent and its children).  In fact, I believe in V5 it is expressly disallowed.  So to have two separate physical / coordinate systems acting on Body, you will probably have to fake one of them.  You could separate Body from Target, and then manually calculate the position of Target based on the position of Body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment regarding separating Body from Target and placing Target under manual control, I imagine it would look like this:

```
Target
|-- Label
|-- Others

Body >> RigidBody
```

Then implement a script something like this on Target

```
public class Follow: MonoBehavior
{
    //This would likely be 'Body'
    public Transform Attached = null;
    //This is the offset you want Target, Label, etc. to be from Body
    public Vector3 Offset = new Vector3(10, 10, 10);

    //Fixed Update is preferred when responding to physical simulation
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Attached != null) transform.position = Attached.position + Offset;
    }
}
```